# References a .net framework dll from a .net 5 web api Could not load type System.Web.HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

We have quite a lot .net framework dlls (no control over) that will never be updated/ported to .net core/5/6

1. Can a .net5/6 web api reference a dll on the .net framework that contains `System.Web`/web services?
2. In short if I wrap all the calls in a .NET Framework dll that is called by a .net 5 web api - will it work?

I tried something and I got an error

> Could not load type System.Web.HttpContext

Where can I find an official document that I can give my boss that says this is not possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell your boss that if you convert the dlls to .net standard 2.0, then you can use the dll in both .net and .net5 projects.

Here is the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: No .NET Framework version supports .NET Standard 2.1, so you probably meant 2.0.

Comment: My bad, sorry it was typo error @LexLi

Comment: @viveknuna I thought about using .net standard but System.Web.Services is not supported by .net standard so I am stuck. Correct?

Comment: What do you want to implement using System.Web.Services? @developer9969

Comment: this web.api will call some existing asmx webservices that will never be ported (no control over)  so I was thinking   .netWebApi 5/6 --->.netframework(dll)---> call asmx web services.. I guess its' not possible.

Comment: You can refer this to call asmx service https://www.thecodebuzz.com/consuming-asmx-web-services-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.HttpContext` only applies to .NET Framework,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to

So what else do you need to tell your boss?

Comment: What I want to establish is that even if is wrapped in a separate dll because is called by a .net 5 web api it will not work. Correct? I just getting paranoid about it that someone might say "well that is not true" kind of thing..  I was looking more of a statement/paragraph  something that "the business" can understand

Comment: @developer9969 Probably tell them that ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are different and incompatible, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and they have to choose only one of the two.

Comment: Regardless of how you wrap it, unless you port it over to use .NET Core, then it’s not compatible - if someone is lactose intolerant, they’re intolerant of milk whether that’s in the form of a glass of milk or in the form of dairy.